# Remove/add struct member with template

Tags: c++, templates, struct

If I have the following structure:

```
struct data1{
   uint8_t data;
} 

template <class T>
struct packetTXMaintenance{
   uint8_t start_byte;
   uint8_t byte_count;
   uint8_t address;
   T temp_parameter;
   uint8_t command_id;
 };
```

For example I can instantiate the struct like this:

```
packetTXMaintenance<data1> value;
```

But it's possible to instantiate the struct without the `template temp_parameter`? (In some case I want the struct without the temp_parameter member, in other case with temp_parameter member with different type `T`)

Comment: What is your criteria for having/not having the `temp_parameter`?

Answer (score 5):

You can specialize the struct for `void` as a template argument and in this implementation you can omit the member:

Just add this right after the declaration of your struct:

```
template <>
struct packetTXMaintenance <void>
{
   uint8_t start_byte;
   uint8_t byte_count;
   uint8_t address;
   uint8_t command_id;
};
```

So when you use `packetTXMaintenance <void> variable` then variable will not have the member, it's a totally different implementation.

Edit:

If you want the member to be with a different type T then you can just instantiate the struct with a different type: `packetTXMaintenance<int>`, in this case `temp_parameter` will have the type `int`.

Comment: Worth noting that static_if might one day appear in the language to solve this elegantly :).